# Apply border on box shadow

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply a border onto the box shadow itself without having to create two individual divs?

Trying to create something like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is the box shadow? I see a solid black block with a border behind it.

Comment: The white part is the box-shadow.

Comment: Stack multiple box shadows.

Comment: @mousesports I see I see, my answer should give you a good idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Josh for both fiddles - much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would go about it with pseudo elements so you don't have to add anymore html.

HTML

```
<div class="box">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}

.box:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Finally a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8M8J/)

Here is a fiddle with a box-shadow on it: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8M8J/1/) or [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8M8J/2/)

Comment: Good catch! Best of luck in your design mate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple box shadows like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/Vm9aM/

```
img {

box-shadow:
    0 0 0 10px hsl(0, 0%, 80%),
    0 0 0 15px hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
```

Comment: 4 ways of doing same thing . nice